# Yamaha P-45's keys feel heavier than Yamaha PSR-F51's

Tags: key, keyboard

I recently bought a second-hand Yamaha P-45 to replace my old Yamaha PSR-F51. But when I tried it, it feels heavy, and the keys are strong; I feel like I don't know how to play the piano.

Is that normal that the keys are that strong compare to my older one?

I never played on a grand piano so I don't know how it feels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if you mean Yamaha **P**SR-F51, you "feel like you don't know how to play the piano" because that is not an *actual* piano keyboard.

A realistic piano keyboard is a *weighted keyboard* (which is what the P45 provides), as it imitates all the aspects of a real piano keyboard: feeling, weight and inertia. Some keyboards even have mechanics that are exactly like those of a real piano.

So, yes, it is normal, as that is what is expected from a realistic keyboard and what piano players are used to.

It will take you some amount of time to get accustomed to it, and you need to be careful when studying and not *force* your fingers and wrists too much. In the end you'll probably realize that a weighted keyboard has benefits, and that "strong" response is actually useful in improving your technique and dynamics.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the advice. It will take some time because even the trill is harder on that piano.

Answer (score 8):

The Yamaha P-45 has weighted keys to make it feel more like playing an acoustic piano.<sup>1</sup> They will feel heavy compared to the PSR-F51, which does not have weighted keys and so are very easy to press.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The [P-45 spec on the Yamaha website](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/pianos/p_series/p-45/specs.html#product-tabs) indicates "Graded hammer standard (GHS) keyboard", which means that the keys at the bass end of the keyboard will feel heavier than those at the treble end. This is consistent with standard piano regulation: the key weights are "graded" from heavier to lighter as one moves up the keyboard from low to high.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>The [PSR-F51 spec](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/keyboards/portable_keyboards/psr-f51/specs.html#product-tabs) indicates that not only are the keys not weighted, but they are not sensitive to touch; that is, no matter how softly or firmly you press them, the level of loudness will always be the same. On the P-45, when you press softly, the sound will be quiet; press more firmly, and the sound will be louder.</sub>